# Connectin S3 to Elastic beanstallk 403 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

im trying to connect my S3 bucket front to my backend on beanstallk and im getting a 403 access denied from the server, i really dont know where the problem lies and i really need directions.

The back is node.jsm all it does is generate JWT for SSO purposes, and the front is a react app, embedding tableau (that is the SSO im trying to achieve by requesting from the server)

here is the code defining my server.js:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const generateJwtToken = require('./genJWT');


const app = express();
app.use(cors(
  {origin: "https://something.something.something-labs.com/", 
    methods:['POST', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE',"FETCH"],
    credentials: true  
  }));

app.use(express.json()); // Handle JSON request bodies

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  try {
    // const username = req.body.tableauUname; // Assuming the JSON structure is { "tableauUname": "username" }
    // const token = generateJwtToken(username);
    
    res.status(200).json({message: "Hello from deployed server"});
    // res.status(200).json({ token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing request body: ", error);
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Bad Request" });
  }
});

app.all('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(405).send('Method Not Allowed');
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // Set CORS header for all responses
  console.error("Global Error Handler: ", err);
  res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Server is listening on port " + port);
  }
});
```

and this is the axios request im making (censored sensitive stuff):

```
  const getJWT = (Username) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const userInfo = {
        Uname: Username,
      };
      axios
        .post("1231231-123123.131231232-123123.131232-123123-123123.elasticbeanstalk.com ", userInfo)
        .then((response) => {
          const token = response.data.token;
          resolve(token); // Resolve the promise with the token
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
           // Reject the promise with the error
        });
    });
  };
```

this all worked locally, and as you can see i have no 403 error handler in my server so it is coming from the beanstallk infrastructure allmost certainly, so i believe it is some sort of configuration that needs to be done in the AWS side, any ideas? im really lost here.

error specifications:

123-123-123-123-123.eu-west-1.r.amazonaws.com:1 (not real)     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

network response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 123123123123123123123123123==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Thansk a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check origins in your CloudFront. In your cloudFront should exist 2 origins:

- for S3
- for backend (elasticBeanstalk)

For each origin, the behavior should be configured. For example, for requests to elasticbeanstalk should exist a behavior:

```
pattern: /api/*
allowed methods: GET, POST, PUT, ...
```

In this case, all routes in your backend api should start from /api prefix.
And CloudFront can distribute requests between S3 and elasticbeanstalk (requests with /api prefix will go to elasticbeanstalk, others - to S3)

Currently it seems that request to elasticbeanstalk just directed to S3 and it leads to an error

Comment: 1. Origin means the code? or is it some config of the s3 and beanstallk infrastructure. if it is for the code, where should implement it. 2. and most importantly why would it direct to the s3 and not the elastic beanstallk when i specified its url, 3. also in the error it does get the 403, from a url which is the front domain (S3) follwoed by a / and the domain of the node server (beanstallk) could that be the problem?

Comment: origin is a setting in CloudFront. As I understand, currently front requests to backend go via CloudFront and in CloudFront POST requests are not allowed